# Is there a way to plot Venn diagram with dot densities for more than 3 sets in R?

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am trying to come up with a solution to plot a Venn diagram for 4 sets with density points inside the circles. The ideal example of what I am looking for is this: https://robslink.com/SAS/democd59/venn_density.htm.

I know that [ComplexUpset](https://krassowski.github.io/complex-upset/articles/Examples_R.html#venn-diagrams) provides such an option, but only for 3 sets. Has anyone come across anything that could host more than 3 sets?

Comment: Just to be clear: have you investigated every CRAN package which mentions Venn/Euler diagrams?